# Where should I place DOM manipulation in AngularJS Components?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angular 1.5.x to develop a control panel which includes, among other things, a grid editor (such as bootstrap).

I am using jQuery UI for differents interactions that the user can make to edit the grid (as dragabble, sortable, etc ...)

I understand that I must create components for different parts of the editor as the Workspace and the different toolbars.

I do not understand is where I should place DOM manipulation.

The components do not replace directives according to documentation. Should I include directives within templates components?

Answer (score -1):

The only place you should be manipulating the DOM is in [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

Take a look at [AngularUI](https://angular-ui.github.io/) as a replacement for JQueryUI

Comment: angular-ui defers to jQueryUI for draggable/sortable. Not really   a replacement.

Comment: @charlietfl "When not to use Components: for directives that need to perform actions in compile and pre-link functions, because they aren't available" - from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component